# What to do if i want to be sure that the consumed message is processed in active MQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I am new in activeMQ, i want to be sure that the consumed message is processed normally and nothing is wrong, and if something gets wrong i don't want to lose the message, in this case what should i do? should i save the messages to a database? is there any way in activeMQ to keep the messages in the queue if something is wrong? i tried to save the messages to mysql database and then called the consumer manually to read from the database, it works but i am afraid in future to have a big record in the database and reading to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a 'Dead Letter Queue' or DLQ to be precise.

Whenever during message processing ,if something goes wrong that message is automatically transferred to Default DLQ provided by ActiveMQ, the queue is named `activemq.DLQ`.

The messages you send should be persistent messages, so that they are stored in DLQ.
for more reference you can have a look here

- http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

hope this helps!

Good luck!